# Multiple foreign keys depending same primary key

Tags: sql-server-2012, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship, composite-primary-key

Let's say that I have a web app that uses SQL Server as database.

I have one table that has 2 foreign keys that contain the same value from other table,

Table `Sections`

```
IDdepartment, IDstore, codTax, accountSell, accountTax, status, m1, m2

-> PK (IDdepartment, IDstore, codTax)
FK (accountSell, accountTax) on AccountPlan (accounCompany)
```

Table `AccountPlan`

```
AccountCod, account, description, account_desc, accountCompany, type, mov) 

-> PK (accountCompany)
```

`accountSell` and `accountTax` depend on `accountCompany`. Both can contain all values available in `accountCompany`.

When I'm doing a query, I want to know the description of that `accountCompany`, how to accomplish this?

Actually I'm using two tables with duplicated data, I think that is possible to have only one table to do the same. Hope that can be possible.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I do hope you don't really have two tables with duplicated data. There is no problem having two FKs pointing to the same table:

```
create table Section
(
  accountSell int not null  foreign key references AccountPlan(accountCompany), 
  accountTax int not null  foreign key references AccountPlan(accountCompany)
)
```

You can get the descriptions by joining to the **same** table twice:

```
select
  sell.description as accountSell_description,
  tax.description as accountTax_description
from 
  Section s
  inner join AccountPlan sell on sell.accountCompany = s.accountSell
  inner join AccountPlan tax on tax.accountCompany = s.accountTax
```

Comment: Before all...
Thanks for your help... Was very important, I should have made all that theoric steps of DB normalization... Because the lack of time in the beginning i have to make some 'hammering', and only now these kind of problems are showing up!! That's a life lesson...